# Running php script from another php script in different folder

Tags: php, call

I have web application that is running in root directory. In another directory I have some application that I want to run and get result from. So from /root/myscript.php I want to call the script /app/index.php which returns some value. The problem is that index.php also includes some scripts which are in /app folder. And because my working directory is in /root directory, this scripts does not get included.

Is there any other way I can run index.php script from myscript.php and enable index.php to include all needed files?

Comment: Maybe something like http://us2.php.net/set_include_path which allows you modify the include path for the duration of a script (i.e. making sure your include path is what you expect for your index.php file).

Answer (score 1):

You can include file from parent directory:

```
include('../somefilein_parent.php');
```

Comment: Not quite sure how this address the two issues laid forth by the question. Is this to execute another script? How do you get it's output? Is this to fix the include path? Because this creates a hard dependency on directory structure for two, potentially unrelated, scripts.

Comment: author, you asked something else?

Comment: Did you read his question? 1) "In another directory I have some application that I want to run and get resoult from." 2) "The problem is that index.php also includes some scripts which are in /app folder. And because my working directory is in /root directory, this scripts does not get included."

Comment: And because my working directory is in /root directory, this scripts does not get included - so he need to include it from parent directory :)